# AppCompat theme for android TV application

Tags: android, television

I'm new in TV layout design. According to reference, TV application use `Leanback` theme system wide and provide some widget and class specially developed for TV. But `Leanback` has very limited features.

I want to create a layout with `TabLayout` which provide by `AppCompact`. For that the activity must use `AppCompact theme` but in Fragment I am using `BrowserFragment` provide by `Leanback`. So when I add `AppCompact` in activity, fragment crash with layout parameter issue.

```
Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Is it not possible to use both theme in TV application?

Comment: It's default application created by Android studio for TV. I just call Fragment from a Activity. If activity use AppCompact theme then application crash with this error. If I use Leanback for the activity then everything is fine. It's not layout, it's Theme. BrowserFragment use Leanback but I am using AppCompact, that's the conflict.

Comment: 1) Can you supply a sample code?
2) Have you noticed that error message says that your layout is missing layout_width attribute somewhere?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: i am also looking for same answer. I want to use TabLayout for TV apps.

Comment: Did you guys find any solution?